# how can i update a persistent variable using transient variable on a submit call of a jsp page in spring mvc hibenate project

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I want to update my persistent list epabxList by making some changes in transient variable deptEpabxList. but my jsp page is returning null value to the object pass to the maincontroller through commandName.

following is my jsp page code :-

**addDept.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" id="depListForm"  action="updateDepart" commandName="departmentDetails">
    <input type="hidden" id="categoryId" name="categoryId" value="${departmentDetails.categoryId} " />
         <h1 class="topheading">Edit Department Details</h1>
             <label class="labelname" >  
               <c:if test="${departmentDetails.categoryId==null}">
               Add New Department
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${departmentDetails.categoryId!=null}">
               Update Department <c:out value="${departmentDetails.categoryName}"/>
                </c:if>
              </label>
        <label class="Labelname3">Department Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="editInput" name="categoryName" value="${departmentDetails.categoryName}">
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:addRow('emailTable','emailList','emailId',${departmentDetails.categoryId})">Add New Email</a>
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:deleteRow('emailTable');" >Delete</a>
        <display:table  class="departmentTable" excludedParams="*" name="departmentDetails.emailList" id="emailTable"
         cellspacing="0">
            <display:column title="Emails">
            <input type="hidden" name="emailList[${emailTable_rowNum-1 }].categoryId" value="${emailTable.categoryId}"/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="editRow" name="emailList[${emailTable_rowNum-1 }].emailId" id="emailList[${emailTable_rowNum }]" value="${emailTable.emailId}"></input> 
            </display:column>
        </display:table><br>
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:addRow('dataEpabx','deptEpabxList','categoryEpabxFax',${departmentDetails.categoryId})"> Add New EPABX</a>
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:deleteRow('dataEpabx');" >Delete</a>
        <display:table id="dataEpabx" class="departmentTable" excludedParams="*" name="departmentDetails.deptEpabxList" cellspacing="0" >
        <display:column   title="EPABX Numbers">
            <input type="hidden" name="deptEpabxList[${dataEpabx_rowNum-1 }].categoryEpabxFaxId" value="${dataEpabx.categoryEpabxFaxId}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="deptEpabxList[${dataEpabx_rowNum-1 }].categoryId" value="${dataEpabx.categoryId}"/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="editRow" name="deptEpabxList[${dataEpabx_rowNum-1 }].categoryEpabxFax" value="${dataEpabx.categoryEpabxFax}"></input>
            </display:column>
        </display:table><br>
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:addRow('dataFax','deptCategoryFax','categoryEpabxFax',${departmentDetails.categoryId})"> Add New Fax</a>
        <a class="hr-add1" href="javascript:deleteRow('dataFax');" >Delete</a>
        <display:table class="departmentTable" excludedParams="*" name="departmentDetails.deptCategoryFax" id="dataFax" 
            cellspacing="0">
            <display:column   title="Fax Numbers">
            <input type="hidden" name="deptCategoryFax[${dataFax_rowNum-1 }].categoryEpabxFaxId" value="${dataFax.categoryEpabxFaxId}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="deptCategoryFax[${dataFax_rowNum-1 }].categoryId" value="${dataFax.categoryId}"/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="deptCategoryFax[${dataFax_rowNum-1 }].categoryEpabxFax" class="editRow" value="${dataFax.categoryEpabxFax}"></input>
            </display:column>
        </display:table>
        <button class="hr-save" value="save" onclick="javascript:updateDepartment('${departmentDetails.categoryId}');" type="submit">SAVE</button> 
    </form:form>
```

this my update method in maincontroller

**MainController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateDepart", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public String update(@ModelAttribute("departmentDetails") JsonMasterCategory depatmentDetailsObj, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
            Model model){
    try{
        if(!result.hasErrors()){                  
            List<CategoryEpabxFax> updatedEpabxList=depatmentDetailsObj.getDeptEpabxList();
            if(CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(updatedEpabxList)){
                for (CategoryEpabxFax Epabx : updatedEpabxList) {           
                    Epabx.setCategory_Type(CategoryType.EPABX);
                    updatedEpabxList.add(Epabx);
                }
                depatmentDetailsObj.setEpabxList(updatedEpabxList);
            }
            baseDataService.updateDepartmentDetails(depatmentDetailsObj);
            model.addAttribute("departmentDetails",depatmentDetailsObj);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.logError("UpdateDepartmentDetails", "Exception while updating the data", e);
    }
    return "addDept";
}
```

this is my model class 
**JsonMasterCategory.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category_master")
public class JsonMasterCategory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    private Integer Category_id;

    @Transient
    private String Category_name;

    @Transient
    private List<CategoryEmail> Emails;

    @Transient
    private List<CategoryEpabxFax> Epabx;

    @Transient
    private List<CategoryEpabxFax> Category_Fax;

    @Transient
    private List<JsonMasterPerson> Persons;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Category_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer categoryId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "Category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryId", targetEntity = JsonMasterPerson.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<JsonMasterPerson> personListD;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryId", targetEntity = CategoryEmail.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<CategoryEmail> emailList = new ArrayList<CategoryEmail>();

    /*@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="categoryId", targetEntity = CategoryEpabxFax.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})*/
    @Transient
    private List<CategoryEpabxFax> deptCategoryFax;

    @Transient
    private List<CategoryEpabxFax> deptEpabxList;



    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryId", targetEntity = CategoryEpabxFax.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<CategoryEpabxFax> epabxList;

    public Integer getCategory_id() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategory_id(Integer category_id) {
        Category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getCategory_name() {
        return this.categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
        Category_name = category_name;
    }

    public List<String> getEmails() {
        List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(this.emailList)) {
            for (CategoryEmail catEmail : this.emailList) {
                emailList.add(catEmail.getEmail_id());
            }
        }
        return emailList;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<CategoryEmail> emails) {
        Emails = emails;
    }

    public List<String> getEpabx() {
        List<String> EpabxList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(this.epabxList)) {
            for (CategoryEpabxFax Epabx : this.epabxList) {
                if (Epabx.getCategory_Type().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("EPABX")) {
                    EpabxList.add(Epabx.getCategory_Epabx_Fax());
                }
            }
        }
        return EpabxList;
    }

    public List<String> getCategory_Fax() {
        List<String> FaxList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(this.epabxList)) {
            for (CategoryEpabxFax Fax : epabxList) {
                if (Fax.getCategory_Type().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("FAX")) {
                    FaxList.add(Fax.getCategory_Epabx_Fax());
                }
            }
        }
        return FaxList;
    }

    public void setEpabx(List<CategoryEpabxFax> epabx) {
        this.Epabx = epabx;
    }

    public void setCategory_Fax(List<CategoryEpabxFax> Category_Fax) {
        this.Category_Fax = Category_Fax;
    }

    public List<JsonMasterPerson> getPersons() {
        return this.personListD;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<JsonMasterPerson> jsonmasterPerson) {
        this.Persons = jsonmasterPerson;
    }

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return this.categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public List<CategoryEmail> getEmailList() {
        return this.emailList;
    }

    public void setEmailList(List<CategoryEmail> emailList) {
        this.emailList = emailList;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<CategoryEpabxFax> getEpabxList() {

        return this.epabxList;
    }

    public void setEpabxList(List<CategoryEpabxFax> epabxList) {
        this.epabxList = epabxList;
    }

    public List<JsonMasterPerson> getPersonListD() {

        return this.personListD;
    }

    public void setPersonListD(List<JsonMasterPerson> personList) {
        this.personListD = personList;
    }
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public List<CategoryEpabxFax> getDeptCategoryFax() {
        List<CategoryEpabxFax> FaxList = new ArrayList<CategoryEpabxFax>();
        if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(this.epabxList)) {
            for (CategoryEpabxFax Fax : epabxList) {
                if (Fax.getCategory_Type().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("FAX")) {
                    FaxList.add(Fax);
                }
            }
        }
        return FaxList;
    }

    public void setDeptCategoryFax(List<CategoryEpabxFax> deptCategoryFax) {
        this.deptCategoryFax = deptCategoryFax;
    }

    public List<CategoryEpabxFax> getDeptEpabxList() {
        List<CategoryEpabxFax> EpabxList = new ArrayList<CategoryEpabxFax>();
        if (CommonUtils.isNotEmpty(this.epabxList)) {
            for (CategoryEpabxFax Epabx : this.epabxList) {
                if (Epabx.getCategory_Type().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("EPABX")) {
                    EpabxList.add(Epabx);
                }
            }
        }
        return EpabxList;
    }

    public void setDeptEpabxList(List<CategoryEpabxFax> deptEpabxList) {
        this.deptEpabxList = deptEpabxList;
    }


}
```

this is my model class for epabxList type:-
**CategoryEpabxFax.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category_epabx_fax")
public class CategoryEpabxFax implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer categoryEpabxFaxId;

    @Column(name="Category_id")
    private String categoryId;


    @Column(name="Category_Epabx_Fax")
    private String categoryEpabxFax;

    @Transient
    private Integer category_epabx_fax_id;

    @Transient
    private String Category_id;

    @Transient
    private String Category_Epabx_Fax;


    public enum CategoryType {
        FAX, EPABX
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CategoryType Category_Type;



    public Integer getCategory_epabx_fax_id() {
        return this.categoryEpabxFaxId;
    }

    public void setCategory_epabx_fax_id(Integer category_epabx_fax_id) {
        this.category_epabx_fax_id = category_epabx_fax_id;
    }

    public String getCategory_id() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategory_id(String category_id) {
        Category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getCategory_Epabx_Fax() {
        return this.categoryEpabxFax;
    }

    public void setCategory_Epabx_Fax(String category_Epabx_Fax) {
        Category_Epabx_Fax = category_Epabx_Fax;
    }

    public CategoryType getCategory_Type() {
        return Category_Type;
    }

    public void setCategory_Type(CategoryType category_Type) {
        Category_Type = category_Type;
    }



    /*-------------------------------------Persistent getters and setters---------------------------------*/

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryEpabxFax() {
        return categoryEpabxFax;
    }

    public void setCategoryEpabxFax(String categoryEpabxFax) {
        this.categoryEpabxFax = categoryEpabxFax;
    }

    public Integer getCategoryEpabxFaxId() {
        return categoryEpabxFaxId;
    }

    public void setCategoryEpabxFaxId(Integer categoryEpabxFaxId) {
        this.categoryEpabxFaxId = categoryEpabxFaxId;
    }
```